# Error: Request failed with status code 502 with aws lambda aws api gateway

Tags: node.js, react-native, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Why am I getting error 502 with aws lambda function and aws api gateway
here is my code from linktokenfunction.js:

```
const client = new PlaidApi(configuration);

const plaidConfig = {
  client_name: 'FinPilot',
  products: ['auth', 'transactions'],
  language: 'en',
  country_codes: ['US'],
};

app.post('/plaidLinkToken', async function (req, res) {
  const linkTokenResponse = await client.linkTokenCreate({
    user: {
      client_user_id: req.body.clientUserId,
    },
    client_name: plaidConfig.client_name,
    products: plaidConfig.products,
    language: plaidConfig.language,
    country_codes: plaidConfig.country_codes,
  });
  try {
    const link_token = linkTokenResponse.data.link_token;
    res.json({link_token});
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

and here is my button add card:

```
 async function getLinkToken() {
    let token = await API.post('plaidTokenAPI', '/plaidLinkToken', {
      clientUserId: '1',
    });
    token = token.link_token;
    setLinkToken(token);
    setShowLinkCardModal(true);
    console.log(linkToken);
  }
```

I am quite new with aws services and cloud but why am i getting this error and how I can fix this?

Unable to post question because code is too much so I have to remove couple of them.

updated code
I just updated my code, I got the function working if I inside my lambda function I change `client_user_id: req.body.clientUserId` to `client_user_id: '1'` it will return link token api for me but if I send user id from front end it's giving me error 502. I tried it on aws api gateway and inside request body I add : `{"clientUserId": "1"}` the cloudwatch did not receive my clientUserId.

```
"data": "{\"user\":{},\"client_name\":\"FinPilot\",\"products\":[\"auth\",\"transactions\"],\"language\":\"en\",\"country_codes\":[\"US\"]}",
```

Comment: The error can be thrown anywhere, we need more evidence, let's check your lambda function output log, you may find it at cloudwatch loggroup.

Comment: I just updated my code, I got the function working if I inside my lambda function I change `client_user_id: req.body.clientUserId` to `client_user_id: '1'` it will return link token api for me but if I send user id from front end it's giving me error 502. I tried it on aws api gateway and inside request body I add : `{"clientUserId": "1"}` the cloudwatch did not receive my clientUserId. 

            "data": "{\"user\":{},\"client_name\":\"FinPilot\",\"products\":[\"auth\",\"transactions\"],\"language\":\"en\",\"country_codes\":[\"US\"]}",